# Saving File in Model in View works but not in Celery Task

Tags: python, django, django-models, celery

I experience this very strang behaviour that when I save a new model instance in my view, the assigned File gets saved, but when I do so in Celery, the instance gets saved, but not the file.

Those is are my views (shortened):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    [...]
    html = render_to_string('pdf/w_html.html', {'request': self.object})
    out = BytesIO()
    HTML(string=html).write_pdf(out, stylesheets=[CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + "/css/pdf.css"), 
                                                  'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Playfair+Display&display=swap'])
    document = Document(product=product, document_type=4,
                        language=1, date=timezone.now().date(),
                        file=File(out, name='Best_Execution_Report.pdf'))
    document.save()
```

Where self.object is a Request instance.
The above code does exactly what it should (ie saving the model and the generated pdf).

But as soon as I modify the above code like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    [...]
    generate_best_execution_report.apply_async(kwargs={'request_id': self.object.pk})
```

with the following celery task:

```
@shared_task
def generate_best_execution_report(request_id):
    """Task to automatically generate best execution Reports and save it to the Documents Model (of the product app)."""
    request_obj = Request.objects.get(pk=request_id)
    logger.info(request_obj)
    html = render_to_string('pdf/w_html.html', {'request': request_obj})
    logger.info(html)
    out = BytesIO()
    HTML(string=html).write_pdf(out,
                                stylesheets=[
                                    CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + "/css/pdf.css"),
                                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Playfair+Display&display=swap'
                                ]
                                )

    logger.info(out)
    with transaction.atomic():
        document = Document(product=request_obj.product, document_type=4,
                            language=1, date=timezone.now().date(),
                            file=File(out, name='Best_Execution_Report.pdf'))
        try:
            document.save()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info(e)

    logger.info(document)
    return True
```

*(please note that request is a one-to-one relation on product, so I have to slightly change how the Document instance is generated)*

The instance will be saved (also the path to the document is correct! No exception is thrown) but the file itself is not going to be saved.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue. The whole App is running in a Docker Environment. The Django app and Celery have been run in separate containers. The problem was that Celery had no access to the Django Filesystem, so the Files got saved, but without reach of the Django Container... Very dumb error, but took me some days figuring out. So if somebody stumbles about the same issues, check your docker volumes.

Comment: Thank you!!! Your comment saved a lot of my time!